# F# match the beginning of an array

Tags: arrays, f#, pattern-matching, f#-3.0

I have a `Byte[]` buffer that may contain one or multiple data frames, I need to read the first bytes to know how long the actual frame is.

This is a "non-working" version of what I want to do:

```
let extractFrame (buffer:byte[]) =
  match buffer with 
    | [|head1;head2;head3;..|] when head2 < (byte)128 -> processDataFrame buffer head2
    | <...others....>
    | _ -> raise(new System.Exception())
```

Basically, I need to evaluate the first three bytes, and then call `processDataFrame` with the buffer and the actual length of the frame. Depending on the headers, the frame can be data, control, etc...

Can this be done with any kind of match (lists, sequences, ...etc...)? Or will I have to create another small array with just the length of the header?(I would like to avoid this).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just evaluate the first three bytes with an if/then ?

Comment: that is what I am trying to find out... There are many cases, and I was wondering the right way of doing this in F#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use matching you could create active pattern (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx):

```
let (|Head1|_|) (buffer:byte[]) =
    if(buffer.[0] (* add condition here *)) then Some buffer.[0]
    else None 

let (|Head2|_|) (buffer:byte[]) =
    if(buffer.[1] < (byte)128) then Some buffer.[1]
    else None 

let extractFrame (buffer:byte[]) =
  match buffer with 
    | Head1 h1 -> processDataFrame buffer h1
    | Head2 h2 -> processDataFrame buffer h2
........
    | _ -> raise(new System.Exception())
```

Comment: Right, this makes much more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think that this might actually be easier to do using the plain `if` construct.

But as Petr mentioned, you can use active patterns and define your own patterns that extract specific information from the array. To model what you're doing, I would actually use a parameterized active pattern - you can give it the number of elements from the array that you need and it gives you an array with e.g. 3 elements back:

```
let (|TakeSlice|_|) count (array:_[]) = 
  if array.Length < count then None
  else Some(array.[0 .. count-1])

let extractFrame (buffer:byte[]) =
  match buffer with 
  | TakeSlice 3 [|head1;head2;head3|] when head2 < (byte)128 -> 
      processDataFrame buffer head2
  | <...others....>
  | _ -> raise(new System.Exception())
```

One disadvantage of this approach is that your pattern `[|h1; h2; h3|]` has to match to the length that you specified `3` - the compiler cannot check this for you.

Comment: I cannot afford to create a new array each time, since it is a server application and would create thousands per second.

Comment: I guess you could come up with something more clever - like return `ArraySegment` :-)

Comment: Right, still thousands of those objects per second :D I feel more relaxed by working with buffer, offset and length... too old school maybe.